# Store variable from loop as array to localStorage

Tags: javascript

What's the way to store result of the `for` loop as array to localStorage? That is, the result should be: `["./somepage1.html", "./somepage2.html"]`.

```
<div class="someclass" href="./somepage1.html">foo</div>
<div class="someclass" href="./somepage2.html">foo</div>

<script>
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    var hrefs = foo[i].getAttribute("href");
    console.log(hrefs);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the Array of hrefs.

This uses `Array.prototype.map` to create a new Array of hrefs from the HTMLCollection of Elements.

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");

var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(foo, function(elem) {
    return elem.getAttribute("href");
});
```

Then serialize it using `JSON.stringify()`, and store it wherever you want in `localStorage`.

```
localStorage.foobar = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

---

Of course, JSON isn't required to store your data. You can serialize it however you want.

You could have used `.join()` instead to create a comma-separated string.

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");

localStorage.foobar = Array.prototype.map.call(foo, function(elem) {
    return elem.getAttribute("href");
}).join(",");
```

Though this isn't the specific result you described.